# How to specify an instance of Tomcat to 'mvn tomcat:run' command?

Tags: tomcat, maven, maven-plugin

When using the Maven plugin, we can start Tomcat from command line using this:

`mvn tomcat:run`

If I have 2 separate installations of Tomcat on my machines, (say Tomcat 6.x and 7.x), is there a way I can specify which one to `:run`???

**EDIT 1:**

As sugested ny Cyril, I tried:

`mvn tomcat6:run and mvn tomcat7:run`

And I got this error:

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat6' in the current project
>   and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
>   available from the repositories [local
>   (/Users/chitteb/.m2/repository), central
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Do you mean `mvn tomcat6:run` and `mvn tomcat7:run`?

Comment: does not work. :( Adding details to questions.

Comment: Have you specified the plugin in the project's pom.xml?

Comment: Try adding the plugin into the project's pom.xml from http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/run-mojo-features.html

Comment: Add `org.apache.tomcat.maven` to `<pluginGroups>` in your `settings.xml` as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html); that will fix the "no plugin found for prefix" error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will run the one specified in `CATALINA_BASE` and `CATALINA_HOME` environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. CATALINA_BASE/CATALINA_HOME variables in which installation? since there are Tomcat installations.

Comment: Hmm, there should be only one specified on your machines. There can't be multiple CATALINA_BASE/CATALINA_HOME. Use Tomcat 7.x.

Comment: Wait a second, I think I get your question. Please look at my other answer.

Comment: Sorry for the above comment, I realized my mistake. Yes, there cannot be multiple of them, and I guess there are by default, CATALINA_HOME is in /usr/share/tomcat7, and CATALINA_BASE is in /var/lib/tomcat. But on my Mac, both of these directories are absent.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to define two different settings by using profiles and use profile name while running.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you give any example/link?

Comment: I am sorry there is no ready made example.  But you can find more details about maven build profiles here http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html and as you already know maven tomcat plugin configuration here http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2/run-mojo-features.html

Answer (score 1):

I found an example of how to adjust tomcat version in the [Apache Tomcat Maven plugin documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2/tomcat6-maven-plugin/examples/adjust-embedded-tomcat-version.html).  If the plugin was configured as shown in the example, you could then specify the version on the `mvn` command line with `-Dtomcat.version=6.0.xxx` or by defining the property in a profile as mentioned by @Seshagiri.

Answer (score 1):

Add below lines in your pom.xml. i was also facing same issue later it resolved

> use mvn tomcat7:run

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>   
        </plugins>
    </build>
```